# Can we conclude that the advertising technique has an impact on sales?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

The impact of three different advertising techniques is being studied by a marketing firm. Sales, in thousand dollars, categorized in four groups are shown for each advertising technique for 200 randomly selected customers  exposed to each technique. Can we conclude that the advertising technique has an impact on sales? Use $\alpha=0.10$. What is p value?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Sales& Technique 1 & Technique 2 & Technique 3 \\ \hline
 0-99&60 &40 &75\\ \hline
 100-199&85  &30 &70\\ \hline
 200-299&20  &70 &30\\ \hline
300-399& 35 &60 &25\\ \hline
\end{array}

So $H_o$= All techniques are equal

and $H_\alpha$= At least one technique has impact on sales

Now I know we need to be using this formula:

$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{(n_i-E(n_i))^2}{E(n_i)}$, where $E(n_i)=np_i$

We can see that n=200, but i'm having trouble getting the $p_i$, do we just focus on one row of sales, where we can get all 3 techniques and use that as our sample size?
For example

Sales 0-99, n= 175, so Tech 1= $\frac{60}{175}$, Tech 2= $\frac{40}{175}$ or am I supposed to apprach this question differently? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $4\times 4$ contingency table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Sales& Technique 1 & Technique 2 & Technique 3 & \text{Total}\\ \hline
 0-99&60 &40 &75 & 175\\ \hline
 100-199&85  &30 &70 & 185\\ \hline
 200-299&20  &70 &30 & 120\\ \hline
300-399& 35 &60 &25 & 120\\ \hline
\text{Total}& 200 & 200 & 200 & 600\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Test statistic:
$$\chi^2=\sum \frac{(n_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}}=
\frac{(60-\frac{175\cdot 200}{600})^2}{\frac{175\cdot 200}{600}}+
\frac{(40-\frac{175\cdot 200}{600})^2}{\frac{175\cdot 200}{600}}+\cdots +
\frac{(25-\frac{120\cdot 200}{600})^2}{\frac{120\cdot 200}{600}}=88.04$$
Critical value:
$$\chi^2_{0.1, df=(3-1)(4-1)=6}= 10.64.$$
Since $88.04>10.64$, we reject the null hypothesis, that is, the technique and the sales are dependent.

Note: $p$-$value=P(\chi^2>88.04)=7.7\cdot 10^{-17}<\alpha=0.1 \Rightarrow$ Reject $H_0$.

Comment: So we do need to do the sum of the whole table then... I see now. Thank you for the very detailed answered!

Comment: Yes. See the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test). Small typo: must be $4\times \color{red}3$ contingency table. Good luck.